# Present UIViewControllers View Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, ios, uistoryboard

In iOS before storyboards I used nibs and used the following code to present a UIViewControllers View. I am trying to figure out how to do this with storyboards. It is crashing when it calls initWithNib. I am open to all suggestions on how to fix this. Thank you in advance.

```
       folderCollectionView = [[FolderCollectionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FolderCollectionViewController" bundle:nil];

        folderView = [folderCollectionView view];
        [folderView setFrame:CGRectMake([[self view] bounds].origin.x, [[self view] bounds].origin.y, [[self view] bounds].size.width, [[self view] bounds].size.height)];
        folderCollectionView.delegate = self;
        [[self view] insertSubview:folderView atIndex:1];
        [[self view] bringSubviewToFront:folderView];
        [folderView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.0f]];

        folderView.alpha = 0.0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
                             folderView.alpha = 1.0;
                         }completion:nil];
```

Comment: Please include the crash log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
   folderCollectionView = [[FolderCollectionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FolderCollectionViewController" bundle:nil];
```

with

```
   folderCollectionView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FolderCollectionViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Make sure you set the identifier in interface builder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With storyboards you usually aren't going to use the iniWithNib method. You do it by calling

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:buttonName];
```

The identifier is set in the storyboard file after you control-drag from one view to another. then to configure the new view you implement

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    folderCollectionView = [segue destinationViewController];
    ...
    // Complete the rest of you view initialization here
}
```

You can read more about storyboards here: [Apple's Storyboards](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html)

Comment: The only thing is I don't want to push my view. I want it to just fade in.

Comment: you can customize the animation of a segue to do whatever you want including fading in. As a matter of fact I believe that is one of the options you can choose when you control drag. (Although I don't remember for sure. You'll have to look) Apple has extensive docs explaining how to customize segues if you're unsure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I did it like this:

```
AddsViewController *addsViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddsViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:addsViewController animated:YES];
```